# property declaration for dispatch_queue_t is a 'Semantic Issue"

Tags: objective-c, properties, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

I am unable to compile `dispatch_queue_t` as a property using the `strong` type. When I revert to `assign`, the thread fails at runtime. I am compiling with OS X 10.10.3 (latest version).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t serialDispatchQueue;
```

I get the error message:

> Semantic Issue: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be object type.

Note that I have read the other listings that indicate the need to compile in OS X 10.8 or later to support ARC. This doesn't seem to solve my problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make the property `assign`, and make sure to actually create the queue and assign the property before you use it.

Comment: I needed to "actually create the queue and assign the property". Thanks for   tip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment by post by Avi the dispatch now works. Here's the object creation declaration that I ommitted:

```
self.serialDispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.selander.GooglyPuff.photoQueue",
                                       DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```